# Cohomology of the sheaf $\mathcal{M}^*$ of invertible meromorphic functions on a Riemann surface

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, riemann-surfaces, sheaf-cohomology, meromorphic-functions

Let $X$ be a Riemann surface and denote by $\mathcal{M}^*$ the sheaf of invertible (i.e. not constantly zero on any connected component) meromorphic functions.

I have seen claims that $H^1(X, \mathcal{M}^*) = 0$. How could one prove this?

Since we have an exact sequence $0 \to \mathcal{O}^* \to \mathcal{M}^* \to \mathrm{Div} \to 0$  ($\mathrm{Div}$ denotes the sheaf of divisors on $X$, which is soft and hence acyclic) this is equivalent to showing that  $H^1(X, \mathcal{O}^*) \cong \mathrm{Cl}(X)$, i. e. that the map $\mathrm{Div}
(X) \to \mathcal{O}^*(X)$ is surjective ($\mathrm{Cl}(X)$ is the divisor class group for $X$).

Comment: Take this with a grain of salt, but I believe $H^1(X, \text{Div}) = 0$ and then the result should follow from the long exact sequence in cohomology. Hope this helps.

Comment: @user313212 This needs that the map $\mathrm{Div}(X) \to H^1(X, \mathcal{O}^*)$ is surjective - which is what I'm trying to prove, but If there is another way to prove it would that's fine too. Do you happen to know how